# Will BufferedReader construction read?

Tags: java, io

Imagine a class `FooParser`. Its constructor accepts an `InputStream` and will serve clients with its `Foo getNext() throws IOException` method. Can I construct the necessary `BufferedReader` (and `InputStreamReader`) at construction time or should I implement the creation in the `getNext()` method when called for the first time? Can my construction be blocked if I create the `BufferedReader` in the constructor of my `FooParser`?

I've read the Java 8 API documentation on `BufferedReader` and I haven't found any conclusive information in regards to my question. The documentation on the constructor does not mention reading or not reading.

Comment: I would be happy if down-voters would leave a comment here about their opinion. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it just prepares the buffer. It does not fill them for the first readLine. You can attach the source files in your IDE, JDK folder, src.zip. And then look into the source yourself.

Comment: That would be sufficient for a specific JDK brand. But there can be other JDK-s where it's not true. On the other hand for my purposes the Oracle and Open sources will be enough.